# ERR_NGROK_6022 whenever I access my flask page using ngrok

Tags: python, flask, web-applications, ngrok

I've a flask webapp on a linux system which was working fine last week, I use ngrok to expose the localhost publicly, but today am presented with this:
[err_ngrok_6022](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QALKw.png)

What I've tried so far:

1. reinstalling ngrok
2. reseting authtoken
3. creating a new account and generating new token

please help

EDIT: Workaround is using pip install pyngrok, apparently new ngrok update is behind this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

question has been solved;
for other people experiencing same issue:

ngrok has been updated, refer to the documentation for changes.

if you don't want to update use pyngrok.

Answer (score 1):

for me I hadn't add the `authtoken` so

```
ngrok config add-authtoken <token>
```

solved it.